Is there a shortcut/hotkey for the Run Http Request in Rider?
I want to run the request where my cursor at with keyboard but cannot find a shortcut for it (configurable ideally).
There is a Run context configuration option that one can use, but it does not quite behave the same way as clicking on the triangle. It also changes the default run configuration which is not a welcome side effect.

